# MySQL config. Need many connections

Tags: mysql, crash, server, config, ram

For my Network I need up to 2000 Connections to my MySQL Server.
First question: Is this possible?

Next thing:

My "my.cnf":

```
[client]
port        = 3307
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /home/MySQL-Server/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3307
basedir     = /opt/mysql/server-5.6
datadir     = /home/MySQL-Server/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /opt/mysql/server-5.6/share
skip-external-locking

key_buffer      = 26M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 2000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M
join_buffer_size = 512M

max_heap_table_size= 32M

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2000

query_cache_limit   = 50M
query_cache_size        = 70M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
slow_query_log      = 1
long_query_time = 2

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
tmp_table_size= 40M
max_heap_table_size = 40M
```

The only thing "mysqltuner" says it isn't good is:

```
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 1011.5G (3215% of installed RAM)
```

So, I don't now how to get this alert away, because sometimes the MySQL server doesn't respond quickly or crashes.

Comment: DBAs would be in a  better position to answer this question, than sw developers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Percona MySQL configuration Wizard. They'll give you sane selections.

[Percona MySQL Configuration Wizard](https://tools.percona.com/)

It's going to be based on your application's usage. If you're running out of space then look at your ram allocation per connection.

[How MySQL uses ram](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-use.html)